# Server modifications happen after restart, why?

Tags: php, nginx

Why whenever I make changes to files within the server, they only change after giving the restart php?

I am currently using **Amazon** server
**Nginx** with **php-fpm**.

The command that normally do for updates happen is:

```
php-fpm service restart
```

**Edit:**

The problem was occurring by cache.

When I restart the php service, the modifications entered

Comment: Are your changes is in nginx conf file?

Comment: @TamilSelvan Which part of the configuration that relates to this?

Comment: The problem was occurring by cache.
When I restart the php service, the modifications entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are changing configuration files and they come into affect only after you restart service.

This is because in linux whenever any service start it will read configuration parameters from configuration files and then starts to run as per those configurations. For ex if you say to any service to do logging into `/var/log/abc` then it will start logging there. And no matter how many times you change conf file after that service will always write logs to that file only. So when anyone change configuration files then service need to be restarted for it to read changed parameters and start running according to those parameters.

Although some services allow to do some runtime paramter changes. But they are not that much in number.

Some applications allow to reload them instead to restart which will read configuration parameters on runtime and change according to them. You can do it this way `service <name_of_service> reload`

Comment: I get it.

But what I was wondering is if this is a problem in using Nginx instead of Apache.
Why usually shared servers or servers that use Apache, you need not make the restart to read new configuration.

I'm thinking that let you configure some of the nginx, which do this automatically.

Comment: @DiegoBorba No you have to restart server for critical configurations either apache or nginx say location of log file. They might be able to pick some configurations at run time but it varies from application to application depending on how they are coded. Please see my edit in answer.

Comment: But that is precisely what I do not.
For example, when I change to the server a .php file, it only shows the change in the browser, when I do restart the php service.
I would like to understand how to make changes to files without needing to restart the php to take effect.

Comment: @DiegoBorba You can try to restart service but apart from that i do not think that without restarting you can make changes to take effect(at least not in my knowledge)